# cross-browser gradients: browser performance issues?

Tags: css, svg, less

I have attempted to tag this question `[subjective]` (it won't let me) because I realise it may be unanswerable, may be common knowledge that I don't know how to find, or perhaps a matter of opinion.

For a few months I've been building commercial web sites using a compiled (LESS) style sheet, with rules like the following every time a background gradient is applied to an element:

```
body {
  background: #592a0e;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiPjxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCBpZD0iZyIgeDE9IjAiIHkxPSIwIiB4Mj0iMSIgeTI9IjAiPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMCIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzJkMTUwNyIgLz48c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiM4NTNmMTUiIC8+PC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD48cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2cpIiAvPjwvc3ZnPg==);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(#2d1507), to(#853f15));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2d1507, #853f15);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2d1507, #853f15);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2d1507, #853f15);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #2d1507, #853f15);
  background: linear-gradient(left, #2d1507, #853f15);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(StartColorStr='#2d1507', EndColorStr='#853f15', GradientType=1);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(StartColorStr='#2d1507', EndColorStr='#853f15', GradientType=1)";
  zoom: 1;
}
```

The SVG inline gradients, compiled in LESS from the start & end colours, are there for IE9.  Otherwise IE9 will display the rectangular IE filter gradient beyond the rounded corners of an element with nonzero `border-radius`.  (Elsewhere in the CSS is set `.ie9 a, .ie9 div { filter: none !important; }` to suppress the IE filters for IE9 only.)

***My question:*** I am worried about possible performance issues and would like to learn how to investigate them fully, or perhaps if these issues are small to discharge these worries for good.  For example, [this site](http://krishna.ie) uses such a background declaration 21 times, based on all the horizontal & vertical gradients, menu items, titles, buttons, and hover properties.

I have no evidence of performance problems on such sites, but how might I determine if the following hypothetical problems could be causing a performance issue, how might I investigate it, and how might I recode to avoid it?

- Does the more complicated CSS lead to slower rendering times?  All such sites are designed to be mobile-friendly so I'm worried the rendering, and maybe the parsing, may be an issue on older mobile browsers.
- To simplify the CSS, and to avoid overusing the browser class `ie9` (we generally use `modernizr` for feature detection), the SVG gradient and the CSS gradient declarations are kept in the same rule set.  The alternative would be much more complicated CSS with separate IE9 rules (with SVG gradient) for every element with a gradient.  In my decision to keep the CSS simple, I'm worried that the code above might be painting the background twice, and that this might lead to a performance problem.
- For non-IE browsers, which already understand the CSS background gradient, is parsing the inline SVG gradient burdensome?  Does this cause a performance degradation every time a page is rendered, or just when the CSS is originally read & parsed?

I am certainly open to correction if I have made any serious errors, left out any important browsers, or neglected any other performance issues.  If anyone is interested I will post the LESS code that compiles the SVG gradients, although it's not related specifically to my question.

Comment: Of course it won't let you tag questions [subjective] - subjective questions go against the fundamental *premise* of the site...

Comment: It would be great to have a [subjective] tag. Why pretend that everything has a right answer?

Comment: Because it's a question-answer site?

Comment: @Omega AKA a debate-the-answer site.

Comment: @watson Check out http://meta.stackoverflow.com if you're interested in the operation of Stack Overflow. Here's some of the debate about the removal of the tag: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51627/should-we-permanently-remove-the-subjective-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Start By Using Browser Inspector Tools**

My suggestion would be to first start by inspecting load times under the Net tab in either Firefox or Chrome.

**You asked**

> Does the more complicated CSS lead to slower rendering times? All such
> sites are designed to be mobile-friendly so I'm worried the rendering,
> and maybe the parsing, may be an issue on older mobile browsers.
>
> For non-IE browsers, which already understand the CSS background
> gradient, is parsing the inline SVG gradient burdensome? Does this
> cause a performance degradation every time a page is rendered, or just
> when the CSS is originally read & parsed?

**As you stated, a bit suggestive. But my recommendations**

Obviously the larger the CSS file the longer it will take to load. Some times large amounts of CSS are unavoidable. You could look into CSS compressors. Or alternatively split your styles into separate style sheets and only load the necessarily styles depending on what device is being used.

I am not super familiar with LESS, as I understand JavaScript does the compiling which makes me wonder why people choose LESS over SASS. This might be a bit nearsighted. But I personally prefer SASS over LESS as all of the Compiling happens server side (*but anyways sort of irrelevant)*.

Assuming LESS works similar to SASS, I would recommend writing a Mixin Specifically for background gradients and then include it into your stylesheets as needed. Maybe make a separate LESS file for IE specific CSS.

Comment: thanks, Kris, especially for the Net Tab in Firebug; I didn't know about that.  I don't know how to get rendering times to display on that graph, or any estimate of CSS processing time, though it seems to show as the difference between red and blue lines.  I'd still be very interested in knowing if there are any possible side effects of my CSS forcing standards-compliant browsers to do unnecessary work, if there's any way of quantifying that.